# Load previous Emacs config if current fails

Tags: emacs

Many times I play with me Emacs config and break it a lot.
Is it possible, in case of a mistake in the config file, to load the previous one that was ok and display some kind of informative error message?

Comment: Are you maintaining copies of your "previous one that was ok"?  Because Emacs certainly isn't.  If you are, where does it live?  And which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: "Are you maintaining copies of your "previous one that was ok"?" - no, that would be a job for some package or something.

Comment: "And which version of Emacs are you using?" Latest available in my distro of choice (NixOS) is 28.2.

Comment: What is your definition of "ok"?  No errors during the init phase is easy enough, but breakage can happen at any time after that.  How should this package know that it's safe to treat a revision as acceptable?

Comment: "No errors during the init phase" - yes, this is good enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trivially "undo" a partially-loaded config, any more than you can trivially undo any other partially-executed software program (which is what your config is -- a software program), and so any such roll-back is going to mean killing Emacs and re-running it with a replacement config.

There's a very common manual solution to your problem -- version control.  If you keep your config under version control then, if you manage to break it, you can roll back to the previous working revision (which in general is something you can establish better than Emacs).

Those steps -- killing Emacs, rolling back the config, and starting Emacs with the modified config -- need to happen anyhow.  It's probably not much bother to do it manually.

I don't have any semi-automated solution for you, but if all you care about is "we reached `emacs-startup-hook` without any errors", then you might use that hook to trigger an rsync of your config directory to your backup directory, and then write yourself a script to execute a rollback by swapping configs.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no built-in facilities for this (and if you are trying to ask for a library which implements this, software recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow).

What you can do in terms of basic hygiene;

- (Obviously) use version control for your configuration files.
- Don't make nontrivial configuration changes in your live running Emacs. What I do is run

  ```
  emacs -nw --debug-init
  ```

  and quit and restart until I have figured out where the problem is.
- Ideally, partition your startup files into a modular structure where you can easily comment out or disable the parts you don't need to debug.

What you are describing seems conceptually straightforward to write in Lisp, perhaps using a version control back end, but then if the Lisp in your startup files is broken, maybe that would break this functionality, too.

Comment: "What you are describing seems conceptually straightforward to write in Lisp" - probably, yes. But I am assuming somebody already did such a package for Emacs.